# Indexing over an array in a struct with an element of the struct

Tags: arrays, rust

Here is my problem: I have this struct Foo

```
struct Foo{
    Bar : 
    Baz : [foo; 5]
}
```

where I want Bar to index over Baz like doing just

```
Baz[Bar]
```

but I don't know what to use.

I have thought of Bar (in the first code) being a usize but I don't think it is really efficient (in the sense of memory and speed) and I think i might fall into using "pointers" so I don't really know what to use.

if someone have something better to come with, thanks in advance for helping me !

Comment: What's `foo` in your array?

Comment: What (not how, but what) do you actually want to do? what is the expected output?

Comment: It's an other struct more or less similar to Foo @ShadowMitia

Comment: Please clarify your question. What you gave us is a struct `Foo` with two members, one of which has no type (?), and the other has a type `[foo; 5]`, where `foo` is an unspecified type apparently "similar to `Foo`". And the desired outcome is to be able to write `Baz[Bar]` - should that be `x.Baz[x.Bar]` where `x` is of type `Foo`? This question is pretty much unanswerable as it stands.

Comment: This sounds like one for the [first rule of optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimization).

Answer (score 1):

Before making it fast, you want to make it work first!

So I understood that you want

```
struct Foo{
    Bar : /* index to element in Baz */
    Baz : [i32; 5]
}
```

Which would be

```
struct Foo{
    Bar : usize
    Baz : [i32; 5]
}
```

Because array indexes are of type `usize`. You can save (maybe) a bit of memory by using `u32` instead of `usize`.

Assuming you're not on some special device, copying around a single number is very fast, regardless of being 32bits or 64bits.

Using pointers won't help you with speed, because of the indirection to access the value in this case. Also it's error-prone and discouraged in Rust (you would have to use an `unsafe` block, and you definitely don't want that for a simple case like this).

More generally, it's way too early for you to be thinking about that kind of optimisation, make your code work first. And then optimise and profile, and decide then what needs improvement. Moving a single number won't be a huge bottleneck!

(And your compiler can optimise away some of this stuff too).

For reference, you can use [Compiler Explorer](https://rust.godbolt.org) if you want to try and understand how "efficient" pieces of code can be.

I've made one [here](https://rust.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:19,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:19,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:19,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:19,startLineNumber:3),source:%27pub+struct+Foo%7B%0A++++Bar+:+u32,%0A+++/*+Bar+:++usize,+*/%0A++++Baz+:+%5Bi32%3B+5%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub+fn+main()+%7B%0A++let+foo+%3D+Foo%7BBar+:+3,+Baz+:+%5B+1,+2,+3,+4,+5+%5D%7D%3B%0A++let+bar+%3D+foo.Baz%5Bfoo.Bar+as+usize%5D%3B%0A++println+!!(%22%7B%7D%22,+bar)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:r1530,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-C+opt-level%3D3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27rustc+1.53.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+Rust%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+rustc+1.53.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) with the above example.

You can hover on "let bar" to see where in the assembly the code is generated. If you change between "u32" and "usize", you'll see that in "--release" mode, you'll get 2 instructions each time. Which is pretty fast!